# Browser not sending `Authorization` header set on deep url to root url

Tags: http, basic-authentication

When I ask user for HTTP Basic Auth at some URL, browser sends `Authorization` header only for this and some other URLs.

Testcase script written in PHP:
http://testauth.veadev.tk/

There are three URLs to ask for credentials (you can use any random).
Logout link (drops current credential after pressing "Cancel" button in browser auth form, not working in IE).
Links to root URL and some test deeper URLs.

Questions:

1. Why browser not sending `Authorization` header at `/` URL if `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized` was sent at `/system/dev`?
   *To repeat: open clean http://testauth.veadev.tk/, click `Auth2`, enter any credentials, you'll be forwarded to `/` after that. You'll see `Auth: null` which means no credentials header was sent by browser.*
2. Why does browser send  `Authorization` header at `/` if `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized` was sent at `/dev`?
   *To repeat: open clean http://testauth.veadev.tk/, click `Auth1`, enter any credentials, you'll be forwarded to `/` after that. You'll see something like `Auth: string 'Basic dHQ6dHQ=' (length=14)` which means credentials header was sent by browser.*
3. If you repeat first case and then click `Auth1` you'll have credentials at `Root` and all other pages. Why?
4. If you click `Auth3` (`/some/deep/and/long/url`) and you'll have credentials at `Page3` (`/some/deep/and/long/3`) and nowhere else. Why?

To clear credential state between tests either restart your browser or click `Logout`, `Cancel` in Auth form and `Root` to return back (Firefox, Google Chrome).

What are the rules of sending `Authorization` header?

Comment: That's indeed a very good question. It might have to do with the number of path elements. Note that it might be relevant how the navigation happens (redirect vs following a link vs entering a URI in the address bar).

Comment: In addition to what Julian said, you are _not_ sending a 401 for `/` according to your script, so the browser should not even have any motivation to send credentials. (_Every_ new protected resource has to send a 401 first, before the browser should send credentials.) And besides that, it is at least doubtful if your test case delivers reliable data, because whether or not PHP has _access_ to the auth data depends on multiple factors.

Comment: It would make sense if browser was sending credentials ONLY for URLs that asked 401. But the browser does send credentials for some URls near the 401 one.
What is a resource in your statement '_Every new protected resource has to send a 401 first, before the browser should send credentials._'?

As for PHP, it really depends, but not in this particular simple case. HTTP sniffer confirms what PHP is getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), section 2 states:

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
>   the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
>   are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
>   the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
>   corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in that
>   space without receipt of another challenge from the server.

If you are using Digest Challenge, section 3.2 states that you may specify a `domain` in the `WWW-Authenticate` header to indicate what the protection space will be. I would try setting that to something like `domain=/`.  I am not sure if this will work with Basic authorization, but it wouldn't hurt to try it; if not, Digest authorization is not much more difficult to work with and is a bit more secure.